# Views filter criteria multiple content types (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7, views

I have created a view and added the filter criteria content type. I have chosen two content types. They are both being displayed. I would like then further filter one of the content types so that only those which have had a check box selected will display. Is it possible to do this in views?

Thanks,
JP

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by modifying the Views filter criteria.

[image: Edit Your View]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Under Filter Criteria you probably added:

Content Type A 
Content type B

Now you can extend this by adding:

Content Type A check-box (is one of: yes or whatever)
Content Type B check-box (is one of: yes or whatever)

Then under Filter Criteria instead of add, click on the arrow and choose "And/Or, Rearrange".

Choose your operator and move the respective fields together.

Then it will look something like this:

> Content Type A 
>  AND
>  Content Type A check-box
>
> OR
>
> Content Type B
>  AND 
>  Content Type B check-box

Comment: this leads to this problem for me : 
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/55188/views-filter-2-content-types-but-with-condition-of-one-of-them/55191

Answer (score 0):

When you expose a filter you can select the option "Limit on selected" or something like this, that force the exposed filter to show only selected filter.

Comment: Thanks for answering Sergiod. Actually, I don't want to have an exposed filter. I'm sorry my question wasn't written more clearly. I want to be able to have one of the two content types being currently displayed to be filter by whether or not I've checked off a box that says archive when creating the node.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and I've posted an answer to this with a screenshot at [Views Filter 2 Content types but with condition on one of them](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/55188/views-filter-2-content-types-but-with-condition-on-one-of-them/114574#114574). Please vote it up if it helps you. Thanks.