# Views Filter 2 Content types but with condition on one of them

Tags: 7, views

I looked up this one before posting: [Views filter criteria multiple content types (Drupal 7)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/43850/views-filter-criteria-multiple-content-types-drupal-7)

And even though the problem is the same, the solutions provided do not seem to work.

I have Content Types A and B. B has a boolean field.

I need to filter and display all As and Bs if boolean is true.

My filter setup looks like this:

Content : Published AND
Content Type : A

OR

Content : Published AND
Content Type : B AND
Boolean Field : True

The Query that gets produced is the following:

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created
FROM `node`
INNER JOIN `field_data_field_boolean` ON node.nid = field_data_field_boolean.entity_id 
  AND (field_data_field_boolean.entity_type = 'node' 
  AND field_data_field_boolean.deleted = '0')
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') 
  AND (node.type IN  ('poll')) )OR( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('webform')) 
  AND (field_data_field_boolean.field_boolean_value = '1') ))
ORDER BY node_created DESC
```

The problem is that Inner Join that gets produced instead of a Left Join for instance.

Which setup would allow me to perform the required filtering?

EDIT: Seems it's a know bug. Related links:
http://drupal.org/node/1766338
[Changing an inner join to a left join in views 3.3?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52449/changing-an-inner-join-to-a-left-join-in-views-3-3)

Comment: Is there any link between Content Type A & B? In other words, does A refer to B in any way?

Comment: nope, none at all.

Comment: I think this is a bug reported at http://drupal.org/node/1766338

Comment: Answering this as a bug/can't be done. For more information visit http://drupal.org/node/1766338

Answer (score 7):

Although this post is quite old, it appears it's still an issue going up to Views 7.x-3.7. Referring to the [post already mentioned here](https://drupal.org/node/1766338) and specifically [comment 36](https://drupal.org/node/1766338#comment-6973984) on that page, I found my working solution.

I had two content types that I wanted to show the title from: an Event and a Blog, however I only wanted the blog posts which had a Boolean field returning as true.  Below is a screenshot of what my grouping filters look like but the trick is, on the Boolean filter, **make sure you select the 'Reduce duplicates' check-box**. Once I did that, I got the results I was expecting.

Hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was missing. Checking the `Reduce duplicates` on each field, changed the query from `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` which made all the content appear

Comment: My god! I've been using Drupal for 8 years or longer and never have I known about this feature until now!

Answer (score 0):

I often struggle with views doing what I want. My solution is to override the automatically generated query with my own.

Below I give you an example of a list of members of the currently viewed group with the specific group role:

```
function mymodule_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
    if($view->name=="og_members") {
        $nid = arg(1);
        $gid = mymodule_get_gid_from_nid($nid);
        $query = db_select('users');
        $query->join('og_users_roles', 'roles', 'users.uid = roles.uid'); 
        $query->addfield('users','name','users_name');
        $query->addfield('users','uid','uid');
        $query->condition('roles.rid', VISITOR_ROLE_ID,'!=');
        $query->condition('roles.gid', $gid,'=');
        $view->build_info['query'] = $query;
    }
}
```

A thing to not here is that returned field should match the fields that the view will expect.

Comment: that kinda defeats the whole purpose though, doesn't it? :)

Comment: You still get the very powerful engine for displaying the results. Access control and other goodies that views give you.
Using gui you will never be able to click-out the more complicated queries.