# How to get all group content from group?

Tags: organic-groups, flags

I am using OG, Flag and Rules module. I would like to do like this.

When a user click **Flag links** in Group (name is `follow_group`) then all group content of that group will be flagged as following.

For now, i'm stuck at getting all group content of specific group. Is there a way to get group content of current group?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59832/show-all-group-content-of-a-specific-group-type check it may it helpful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the contents are associated in `og_membership` table. If you can get the `gid` (group node id), then it will be easier to get the content associated with that group.

```
$og_contents = db_select('og_membership', 'ogm')
->fields('ogm', array('etid'))
->condition('ogm.gid', $gid, '=')
->condition('ogm.entity_type', 'node', '=')
->execute()
->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Cool, it worked.